# DirectX notation meaning of "m_pXxx"

Tags: visual-c++, directx

`m_pXxx` appears a lot in DirectX sample code, e.g. `m_pBitmap` here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd756684%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

I know the `p` means pointer, but what does `m` mean?

Couldn't find it using google, not sure what to search for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`m_variableName` is usually a member variable of a file or class. This is an optional naming convention. You will also see `_variableName` at times as well. For example:

```
class MyType
{
private:
   int m_age;
   int m_height;
public:
   void DoSomething();
};
```

Therefore, in the example you posted the `m_variableName` is presumed to me a member variable of a class or file that simply isn't explicitly outlined in the code sample.

Comment: A name that start with a leading `_` is reserved by the c++ standard. personally, i use `variableName_`, some use `mVariableName`, etc. Do you choice but having a simple way to differentiate global, local and member varibale is a good habit.